# Combine manipulate and plot of a result of NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I wish to manipulate the following for different values of k, using Matheamtica 10:

```
QQ = NDSolve[{FF''[x] == -k^2*FF[x], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}, 
FF[x], {x, 0, (2 Pi)/k}] 
Plot[FF[x] /. QQ, {x, 0, 2 Pi/k}]
```

The following attempt examples do not work (return multiple errors)... what does?

Fail 1:

```
 Manipulate[
 QQ = NDSolve[{FF''[x] == -k^2*FF[x], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}, 
 FF[x], {x, 0, 2Pi/(k)}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001], {k, 0, 5}] 
 Plot[FF[x] /. QQ, {x, 0, 2Pi/(k)}]
```

Fail 2:

```
Manipulate[
Plot[FF[x] /. 
NDSolve[{FF''[x] == -k^2*FF[x], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}, 
FF[x], {x, 0, 2Pi/(k)}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001], {x, 0, 2Pi/(k)}], {k, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: You cannot have `x` be a symbolic variable if it is assigned a numeric value.  E.g. `Plot[.., {x, 0,..}]` assigns `x` to be a number.  And `k` cannot be `0`, since you divide by it.

Comment: @Michael E2 2:     I wish to manipulate k, and plot over x's.

Comment: But `Plot` assigns numbers to `x`.  That messes up `NDSolve`, since `x` is no longer a variable.

Comment: ok, maybe I don't explain myself well: Think of 'k' as eigenvalues. For each 'k' I wish to find numerically the eigenfunction, and then plot it over a range of x's. There one whole function of 'x' for each 'k' mode...

Comment: Note that `ParametricNDSolve`, which is what I'd normally suggest for this sort of problem, doesn't seem to work for boundary value problems.

Comment: Also, as an aside:  is it intentional to set the boundaries of the ODE system at $0$ and $\pi/2k$, and then plot from $0$ to $2\pi/k$?

Comment: @user1611107 See my update for an explanation of what I meant. We were missing each other's points. :)

Comment: @ Michael Seifert:  Yep, it was intentional, since the solution is actually known; cos[kx] of-course, and I wanted to see the same shape in the plot for any 'k'. It does not matter for the question though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
  With[
    { QQ = First @ NDSolve[
        {FF''[x] == -k^2*FF[x], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}
      , FF[x]
      , {x, 0, 2 Pi/(k)}
      ]
    }
  , Plot[FF[x] /. QQ, {x, 0, 2 Pi/(k)}]
  ]
, {k, 0.001, 5}
]
```

---

*Reply to comment above:*

Maybe I don't explain myself well, either :) -- OK, so `k = 0` is a problem because of `2Pi/(k)`, but that's easy to fix. When that is fixed, the reason your second code still fails has nothing to do with `k`. You're conceiving of there being one function of `x`, but that's not how the code actually works. First of all `Plot` holds its arguments.  That means the expression it sees is this:

```
FF[x] /. NDSolve[{FF''[x] == -k^2*FF[x], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}, 
  FF[x], {x, 0, 2Pi/(k)}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]
```

`Plot` then evaluates this expression at several values of `x`. Take, say, `x = 0.123`; then `Plot` tries to evaluate the following, which generates errors:

```
FF[0.123] /. NDSolve[{FF''[0.123] == -k^2*FF[0.123], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}, 
  FF[0.123], {0.123, 0, 2Pi/(k)}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]
```

This doesn't work because there is no independent variable `x` in the code at this point.  The `x` inside `NDSolve` needs to be a symbol for `NDSolve` to work; the `x` in `Plot` needs to be set equal to a number for `Plot` to work.  These two `x` need to be separated in some way for the whole to work.

For instance, changing one of the `x` to `y` works, but it's very slow because the BVP is solved hundreds of times per plot:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[FF[x] /. 
   NDSolve[{FF''[y] == -k^2*FF[y], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0}, 
    FF[x], {y, 0, 2 Pi/(k)}],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi/(k)}],
 {k, 0.001, 5}]
```

For real efficiency, the following simply connects the steps `NDSolve` takes, which are usually small enough to make a good graph:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot@
  NDSolveValue[{FF''[x] == -k^2*FF[x], FF[0] == 1, FF[Pi/(2 k)] == 0},
   FF, {x, 0, 2 Pi/(k)}],
 {k, 0.001, 5}]
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot :)